# Zend DB call to undefined method where()

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

The below query returns a `Call to undefined method Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet::where()` error.

```
$rowset = $this->table->select()->where("email='$str'");
```

This however works:

```
$rowset = $this->table->select(["email" => $str]);
```

Here are the dependencies:

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Where;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\RowGatewayFeature;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\MetadataFeature;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\FeatureSet;
```

Anyone knows why?  I'm basically just trying to use 'where' to run an `OR` MySql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out from the obvious error message indicated that the method select would return a result set. I think I was looking at sources for a different Zend DB version.  This answer is for version 2.9.

Here's how to customize the select options:

```
$select = new Select;
$select->from("table_name");
$select->where("email='$str' OR uid='$str'");
$rowset = $this->table->selectWith($select);
```

Hope this eventually helps someone.